# Keras model.fit does not complain incompatible shape?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I defined my model starting with `inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(512, 512, 3), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)`. Then I use model.fit with data of shape (1, 720, 1280, 3). The model still trains normally and the loss decreases. Why is that?

Thanks.

I tried to train with same shape. But the result did not turns out to be good.

So here is the code:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(512, 512, 3), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE) # REVISE,
x = tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D(cropping=((256, 0), (0, 0)))(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Resizing(66,200)(x)
# x = x / 255
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(24, (5,5), (2,2), activation="elu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(36, (5,5), (2,2), activation="elu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(48, (5,5), (2,2), activation="elu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="elu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="elu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='elu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='elu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='elu')(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
print(model.summary())

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=1e-3) 
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)

img_gen = image_data_generator(X_train, y_train, batch_size=1)
X = next(img_gen)[0]
print(X.shape)
print(model(X).shape)


# saves the model weights after each epoch if the validation loss decreased
checkpoint_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=os.path.join(model_output_dir,'lane_navigation_new_nvmodel_big2'), verbose=1, save_best_only=True) # revise

with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
  history = model.fit(image_data_generator( X_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE), # 重要！batch_size大了好训练，1个batch_size训不出东西！
                                steps_per_epoch=10, # 300
                                epochs=300,
                                validation_data = image_data_generator( X_valid, y_valid, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE),
                                validation_steps=10, # 200
                                verbose=1,
                                shuffle=1,
                                callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
```

Comment: Full code please

Comment: @mujjiga added already

Comment: to me seems that you are using the right shape

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Sorry I uploaded the wrong version of code.

Comment: Hi @FrankChen, I have executed the above mentioned model with random data, it only works with the given input shape and getting error while executing with the (1,720,1280,3). Please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/4ead54c3370e87ccc2d39ae7fed0dc8a). Thank You.